# increase the value of a variable each time that it is called from a controller

Tags: c#, api

I am using an API to send variables to local host in XML

```
public class LocationController : ApiController
{

    Location[] injury = new Location[]
     {
         new Location 
            { 
                Latitude= 51.41459808, 
                Longitude = -5.43823242, 

            },

     };
    public IEnumerable<Location> GetProducts()
    {
        return injury;
    }
}
```

I am sending coordinates to the xml file, to be utilised by a database later.

```
public class Location
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public int Pulse { get; set; }
}
```

The question that I have is: Is it possible to have the Latitude and Longitude values increase (or decrease) slightly as they are called, over time?

I want the values to drift to signify that the target is moving, so that I can plot a path that they are taking on a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the same Location object over and over, this may do the job:

```
public class Location
{
    private double latitude;

    public double Latitude
    {
        get
        {
            latitude += offset;
            return latitude;
        }

        set
        {
            latitude = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But use this for testing purposes only. Changing values in a getter is **evil**.

Comment: Agreed, while this may work, having side effecting getters is usually a bad idea.  Best to make this a seperate function call that updates the value and returns a field.